# What happened to the CSS Checker tool?

Tags: html, css, orphan

I used it before, and was reminded of it when someone asked about a tool to strip unsused CSS from a stylsheet.

I went back to the link, but it's gone, what happened to it? Is it gone forever or does anyone know of a backup? Or a similar tool that can still check your CSS against the HTML and strip orphan CSS.

Thanks.

[Link](http://services.immike.net/css-checker/) (to broken site for reference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Dust-Me Selectors](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dust-me-selectors/).

Alternatively, consider [some of the following](http://www.labnol.org/internet/design/css-tools-strip-unused-styles-compress/3879/)...

Comment: Thanks, I've already seen that page, and it lists the tool I want to use, the second one down. Strange it's gone.